# Python Maximal, Minimal and Sum Program

Tags: python

I need some help creating a python program that does the following:

```
 Execution:
Enter an integer: 10
 Enter an integer: 5
 Enter an integer: 3
 Enter an integer: 0

Numbers entered: 4
Sum: 18
Max: 10
Min: 0
```

I currently have this and I am stuck:

```
user_input = " "
while user_input != "":
      user_input = input("Enter a number, or nothing to quit: ")
      if user_input != "":
            user_input = int(user_input)
            user_input += 1
            print(user_input)
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 2 strategies: 1/ collect inputs and compute at the same time 2/ collect then compute. what is your choice?

Comment: 2? Collect then compute. Can you please show me how? Would be much appreciated

Comment: Then, in which collection do you memorize the inputs? Other problem you use `user_input` for 2 incompatible purposes : 1/  the int of input 2/ count of inputs.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You can first collect the inputs in a list, and then print the results, where f-strings are handy:

```py
lst = []
while (user_input := input("Enter a number (blank to quit): ").strip()):
    lst.append(int(user_input))

print(f"You have entered {len(lst)} numbers:", *lst)
print(f"Sum: {sum(lst)}")
print(f"Max: {max(lst)}")
print(f"Min: {min(lst)}")
```

If you are not familiar with walrus operator `:=`, then

```py
lst = []
user_input = input("Enter a number: ").strip() # ask for input
while user_input != '': # check whether it is empty (!= '' can be omitted)
    lst.append(int(user_input))
    user_input = input("Enter a number (blank to quit): ").strip() # ask for input
```

Example:

```
Enter a number (blank to quit): 1
Enter a number (blank to quit): 2
Enter a number (blank to quit): 3
Enter a number (blank to quit):
You have entered 3 numbers: 1 2 3
Sum: 6
Max: 3
Min: 1
```

Comment: At the end of the while line  `!= ''`  can ne removed.

Comment: @hpchavaz You are right!

Answer (score 0):

Detailed version:

```
user_inputs_values = []
user_inputs_count = 0                             # (a)
user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
user_inputs_values.append(int(user_input))
user_inputs_count += 1                            # (a)
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter another number, or enter to quit: ")
    if not user_input:
        break
    user_inputs_values.append(int(user_input))
    user_inputs_count += 1                        # (a)
print(f"Numbers entered: {user_inputs_count}")    # (b)
print(f"Sum: {sum(user_inputs_values)}")
print(f"Max: {max(user_inputs_values)}")
print(f"Min: {min(user_inputs_values)}")
```

Note that the first input message is different than the following ones.

Note using a count of entries is also possible, taas the count is equal to len(user_inputs_values). So you can remove lines marked (a) and replace line marked (b) with:

```
print(f"Numbers entered: {len(user_inputs_values)}")
```